# Como chamar uma função no javascript pelo enter do teclado Android?

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Boa noite.
Estou estudando e preciso na verdade eram 3 coisas mas se puderem ajudar com apenas 01 já está bom,
 tentei pesquisar e apliquei muitas dicas de vários sites mas não tive sucesso. Preciso que o botão "Enter (seta) dentro do Android"chame a função especifica dentro do button "buscar". se configuro o botão como "input button" o enter não faz nada e se configuro apenas como "button" o enter dá pagina de erro. Resumindo o código javascript pesquisa dentro do array objeto pelo numero de cancelamento da lista e imprime em uma tabela. Obs. o código funciona mas aqui não consegui fazer rodar.

1 - centralizar o h1 - nao consegui na tela do Android 9
2 - trazer a section para esquerda - 
3 - pergunta = fazer o botão enter android chamar a função

[image: teste realizado]

```js
<script type = "text/javascript">


const lista = [
{loja:100,cancelamento:123,atendimento:'Autorização Nº1077229',data: '01/01/2020',
 status:'Resolvido'
},

{loja:200,cancelamento:456,atendimento:'Enviado para Administradora',data: '02/02/2020',
status:'Resolvido'
},

{loja:300,cancelamento:789,atendimento:'Não é permitido cancelamento parcial',data: '03/03/2020',
status:'Aguardando Filial'

}
]    

/*
cancelamento.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    buscar();
}
}); */

function handleEnterKeyPress() {
    console.log('Enter key pressed')
  }
  
  window.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
    console.log(event.code, event.key);
    
    if (event.code === 'NumpadEnter' || event.code === 'Enter')
      buscar();
  });

function buscar() {
        
var cancelamento = document.getElementById('cancelamento')
let buscar = Number(cancelamento.value)
let result = document.getElementById('res')
let listagem = document.getElementById('listagem')
let table = document.getElementById('table')




    

const procurar = lista.find( obj => obj.cancelamento === buscar )//buscar 
        console.log( procurar )   
        console.log(`lista ${lista}`)
        console.log(buscar)
        console.log(lista[0].atendimento)
        console.log("testando" + typeof(procurar))
        console.log("testando" + typeof(lista))


if(procurar != undefined){
    
   document.getElementById('loja').innerText = "Loja"
   document.getElementById('cancelamentoTabela').innerText = "Cancelamento"
   document.getElementById('atendimento').innerText = "Atendimento"
   document.getElementById('data').innerText = "Data"
   document.getElementById('status').innerText = "Status"

    var lojaRes = document.getElementById("lojaRes")
    var cancelamentoRes = document.getElementById('cancelamentoRes')
    var atendimentoRes = document.getElementById("atendimentoRes")
    var dataRes = document.getElementById("dataRes")
    var statusRes = document.getElementById("statusRes")
                 
   document.getElementById('lojaRes').innerText = procurar.loja
   document.getElementById('cancelamentoRes').innerText = procurar.cancelamento
   document.getElementById('atendimentoRes').innerText = procurar.atendimento
   document.getElementById('dataRes').innerText = procurar.data
   document.getElementById('statusRes').innerText = procurar.status
   
   console.log("testando" + typeof(procurar.status))
   if (procurar.status == "Aguardando Filial") 
    { statusRes.style.backgroundColor = '#FF0000';}

    else 
    { statusRes.style.backgroundColor = '#32CD32';}

   listagem.innerText = " "
   var div = document.getElementById('div')
   div.style.display = 'block';
   cancelamento.focus()
   document.getElementById('cancelamento').Number = ""
            
}if (procurar == undefined) {
    listagem.innerText = "Cancelamento não localizado!"
    var div = document.getElementById('div')
    div.style.display = 'none';
    cancelamento.focus()
    document.getElementById('cancelamento').Number = ""
    
}   
          
}

var button = document.getElementById('button')
button.addEventListener('click',mudaBackground);
function mudaBackground() {
thead.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(85, 167, 221)";
thead.style.border = "2px solid black";
lojaRes.style.border = "2px solid black";
cancelamentoRes.style.border = "2px solid black";
atendimentoRes.style.border = "2px solid black";
dataRes.style.border = "2px solid black";
statusRes.style.border = "2px solid black";

document.getElementById('loja').style.border = "2px solid black";
document.getElementById('cancelamentoTabela').style.border = "2px solid black";
document.getElementById('atendimento').style.border = "2px solid black";
document.getElementById('data').style.border = "2px solid black";
document.getElementById('status').style.border = "2px solid black";

console.log(procurar)
if (procurar.status = "Aguardando Filial") {
{ statusRes.style.backgroundColor = '#FF0000';
}
}else { statusRes.style.backgroundColor = '#32CD32';}

}
  




</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Cancelamento</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://sites.google.com/site/cancelamentocreddvol/estilo.consulta.css">

</head>
<header>
  <h1 class="h1" id="h1">Consulta Cancelamento</h1><br>
</header>

<body>

  <section class="section" id="section">
    <div>
      <input type="number" class="cancelamento" name="cancelamento" id="cancelamento" autofocus="cancelamento"><input type="button" class="buscar" value="buscar" onclick="buscar();mudaBackground();" id="button">

    </div>

    <div id="res" class="res">

      <strong> <p id="listagem"></p> </strong>

    </div>

    <div id="div">
      <p id="listagem2">
        <table class="table" id="table">
          <thead class="thead" id="thead">
            <th id="loja" class="th"></th>
            <th id="cancelamentoTabela" class="th"></th>
            <th id="atendimento" class="th"></th>
            <th id="data" class="th"></th>
            <th id="status" class="th"></th>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="tbody">
            <td id="lojaRes" class="td"></td>
            <td id="cancelamentoRes" class="td"></td>
            <td id="atendimentoRes" class="td"></td>
            <td id="dataRes" class="td"></td>
            <td id="statusRes" class="td"></td>
          </tbody>
        </table>

      </p>
    </div>

  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A soluçao infelizmente não encontrei aqui no Stackoverflow mas agradeço ao Costamilam que deu um norte e ajustei o codigo, acredito que tudo se passava por algum motivo na declaração do input button onde mudei de "input type="button"" para apenas um button e removi o type e tirei o input e o button de dentro de um form que era este ultimo que nao deixava o evento de teclado entrar para chamar as funçoes.Tentei apos alinhar os input e button no conteiner mas nao consegui centralizar-lo na pagina.

Mas tento em outra pergunta

https://tfnicolau.github.io/[finalizado](https://tfnicolau.github.io/)

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o [KeyboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent), provavelmente a melhor opção é o event `keyup`, pois ele será disparado uma única vez mesmo se o usuário manter a tecla pressionada. Então basta verificar qual tecla foi pressionada através das propriedades [`code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) ou [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)

```js
function handleEnterKeyPress() {
  console.log('Enter key pressed')
}

window.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
  console.log(event.code, event.key);
  
  if (event.code === 'NumpadEnter' || event.code === 'Enter')
    handleEnterKeyPress();
});
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Tentei implementar seu codigo e tambem não consegui fazer funcionar no Enter do Android. ate achei outro codigo mas sem sucesso.                                      cancelamento.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        buscar();
    }
    })

Comment: A propriedade `event.keyCode` está obsoleta, cuidado ao utilizar. Tente executar esse código pelo navegador desktop usando o teclado mobile emulado e olha no console qual o code que irá aparecer. Ou então troque o `console.log` por um `alert` e teste no celular mesmo

Comment: Obrigado pela dica. infelizmente não consegui implementar o código do amigo talvez eu não expliquei direito: o que preciso é que a função seja chamado pelo botão ( funcionando ok) ou pelo "enter no teclado android". A forma que testo é passando o arquivo.html para o celular e abrindo no navegador. ate coloquei o link do script original https://sites.google.com/site/cancelamentocreddvol/stack.js

Comment: Usando o código abaixo consegui fazer a busca com o Enter mas não fica impresso na tela, mostra e limpa a tela.    <script type="text/javascript">
              
                document.getElementById("cancelamento").onkeypress = function(event){
                    if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.which == 13){
                      buscar();
                    }
                };
            </script>

Comment: Parece que o problema é outro, se for o caso, abra outra pergunta. Não faça muitas perguntas juntas, se resolveu esse problema, marque a melhor resposta como correta

Comment: Mas não resolvi , ainda estou tentando chamar a função com o enter do teclado no android e também com o botão ( que já funciona ).